# Why does my synthesized 4-bromoacetanilide smell like almonds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, smell

So, I synthesized 4-bromoacetanilide in the lab by brominating acetanilide. Acetic acid was used as a catalyst. Sodium bisulfide was used to neutralize the reaction product. Then it was washed with water and recrystallized in ethanol. After that I let it dry for a week. Then I added a little water by accident but decided to store it anyways, and a few weeks later I opened the stored product and I smelt almonds. It wasn't even a weak odour, it was much like benzaldehyde, but not that strong. How would this even be possible? I can't figure it out.

2-bromoacetanilide might have been formed. I did search a little bit, and found that the decomposition of 2-nitroacetanilide - a similar product - results in hydrogen cyanide (almonds smell; very toxic). But it cannot be that, can it? Wouldn't I be like dead by now? Sniffed it three times. Or is it not really toxic at very low concentrations, but smellable?

The smell was kindof pleasant, less aromatic-like than benzaldehyde. Not strong, but also not weak when I held it close. People say HCN smells like burned or roasted almonds, but it was more like a sweet but bitter maybe ester-like odour. Something probably most similar to marzipan.

[image: acetanilide, 4-bromoacetanilide, 2-bromoacetanilide]

[SDS Source](https://www.fishersci.com/shop/msdsproxy?productName=AC352500050&productDescription=2-NITROACETANILIDE%252C%2098%2525%205GR&catNo=AC35250-0050&vendorId=VN00032119&storeId=10652)

Comment: Just because two compounds are different doesn't mean that they don't smell the same...

Comment: 4-bromoacetanilide isn't supposed to smell like almonds though. It's one step away from being paracetamol, and acetanilide itself doesn't smell either.

Comment: I haven't heard anybody using the word 'bromizing' until I checked [google](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=2Bs6XPrzBZne9QONuKPgCQ&q=bromizing+definition&oq=bromizing&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0i30.1348.3829..5856...0.0..0.261.1995.0j2j7......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..0i131j0j0i10.53-DKghBkMI). I use the word 'brominating'.

Comment: That's because I'm Dutch, not sure how that got in my mind but I guess it's closest to the Dutch word: bromeren.

Comment: I remember how "*Brombeeren*" (German name for blackberries) confused me at first. I was stupid enough to ask whether there are "Chlorbeeren" though, so... (German is not my first language, just in case:) )

Comment: It might be hydrolysis product of 4-bromoacetanilide, [4-bromoaniline](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/7807), which is described to have “sweet odor”.

Comment: You may actually be pretty correct, thank you. I had expected hydrolysis to form paracetamol, [but apparently not](https://cdn1.byjus.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/chemistry/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/t2.png).